# MYSQL connect to Go Daddy

Tags: mysql, remote-access

How to connect MYSQL workbench to GoDaddy Server?

I have created database in GoDaddy and have username and password of that database and also the user for that database .
I dont know how to connect GoDaddy Database from mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using simple steps.

> 1. Go to your GoDaddy product page
> 2. Under Web Hosting, next to the Linux Hosting account you want to use, click Manage.
> 3. In the account Dashboard, click cPanel Admin.
> 4. In the cPanel Home page, in the Databases section, click Remote MySQL.
> 5. Under Add Access Host, in the Host field, enter the IP address from which you want to access your databases.
> 6. Click Add Host

refer this link for further information https://in.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-a-mysql-database-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16103

Comment: I have already added host